# How are open source repositories managed for popular languages?

Tags: open-source, management, dependency-management, package-managers

I'm a developer that creates Open Source code for a small language (LabVIEW), and am currently sharing this in several places. The vendor of LabVIEW has a certification process for Open Source libraries (mixed with commercial/closed libraries), but it's rather lengthy.

I was wondering how more popular languages manage large repositories of libraries (for instance Debian, or python-works) of Open Source libraries, are those strictly controlled and monitored for quality or can anyone contribute?

- How would one set up the process for a centralized repository and accept incoming code?
- Are there different levels of quality/trustworthy?
- Is it allowed to rely on libraries outside the repository?

Answer (score 1):

The classic example i would like to refer is may be the [*Kernel.org*](http://www.kernel.org) where Linux kernel is hosted. Comitters can either submit a patch (mostly they can have account on kernel.org). While there is no restriction on submitting the patch, however, it doesn't go straight away into the main line.

Linus Torvalds, even till date validates each patch and he is a final authority to permit or reject each patch.

Apache on the other hand has a vision of [shared leadership](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~taylor/ics280e/ApacheLeadership.pdf).

In all projects usually, there are no barriers to contributing however, there are always some core people who are trusted and only they announce the releases to ensure that things work fine.